# Have any of the Star Trek series themes ever appeared in-universe in an episode?

Tags: star-trek, music, theme-music

Each Star Trek show has its own theme music, played during the opening credits. Have any of these theme songs appeared in-universe, e.g. as music someone is listening to or as music a character is singing or playing on an instrument? Do these themes exist in-universe, e.g. as an anthem for the federation?

Comment: BTW a handy musical term here is *leitmotif*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

TVTropes has a page about this: [Theme Tune Cameo](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThemeTuneCameo). It lists several *Star Trek* examples. For example, here's the DS9 theme being played in Quark's bar, in the episode "Sanctuary":

Comment: For those who don't want to click through (because, you know, TV Tropes), the other examples cited are: (1) In Star Trek: The Original Series, a light cocktail bar version of the theme was played, appropriately, in a bar in "Court Martial" and at a cocktail party in "Conscience of the King." (2)
An episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation had a string quartet preparing to play in Ten-Forward, and during the warmup the theme tune of the show is subtly played. (3) In the pilot, the theme song is fully reprised to accompany the Enterprise's first saucer seperation sequence.

Comment: (4) "Sanctuary" in Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, where the instrumentalist Varani plays the theme music for a rapt audience. (5) In "Fascination" in the third season of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine, Odo conducts a bajoran band playing a hardly recognizable version of the theme song.

Comment: @Nathaniel: 3 isn't diegetic though, is it? Unless space carries sound and the Enterprise blasts the TNG theme out of hull-mounted speakers when separating...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I guess not, now you come to mention it. (I'm just reporting what's on the tvtropes page.) (Though space does seem to carry sound in ST:TNG, at least as far as the camera is concerned, so I guess it's not impossible, though unlikely!)

Comment: @Nathaniel: Actually giggling at the thought of it. I mean, why not?!

Comment: “Unless... the Enterprise blasts the TNG theme out of hull-mounted speakers when separating...” — Can we all just decide that’s canon now? In *The Best of Both Worlds Part 2*, the Borg would have been all _“MUSIC IS IRRELEVANT. BUT WE DO FIND OURSELVES WONDERING HOW WE CAN HEAR IT THROUGH THIS VACCUUM?”_

Comment: modulated tractor beams to the cube's hull.

Comment: It's a little frustrating that the reference to TNG is just "an episode".  Which episode?  I want to go listen!

Comment: Found it, it's in Season 3x02, "Ensigns of Command".  It's really, really subtle, it's not the fanfare line, it's a line out of the original theme.

Comment: "here's the DS9 theme being played in Quark's bar, in the episode 'Sanctuary'" - I do hear certain similarities, but I think it is a stretch to claim the music played there is the same as the DS9 theme.